# How to start Aws workflow execution from a web application

Tags: amazon-web-services, workflow, amazon-swf

I have just started learning AWS Simple workflow service and wrote a workflow using AWS Flow framework for Java. I am able to execute the workflow successfully from eclipse. But for my requirement, I need to execute it from my web application back-end which I am planning to write using Nodejs. I found AWS Restful service for SWF but not sure if it will work with flow framework. So please help me in taking the right approach.

So basically my question is how can I execute workflow starter and workers from web back-end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [A Node.js library for accessing Amazon Simple Workflow](https://github.com/neyric/aws-swf). But this library is pretty low level comparing to AWS Flow Framework making writing complex workflows really non trivial. 
You might consider only starting workflows and implementing activities using Javascript and implementing workflow decider using Java AWS Flow Framework.